# NoClassDefError when running a method

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

When i try to run the following code the following error pops up and I do not know why, it worked literally 10 minutes ago

```
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventPostProcessor(newKeyEventPostProcessor() {
        public boolean postProcessKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                if(e.isControlDown() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P){
                    printSinglePage();
                    e.consume();                           
                }
                if(e.isControlDown() && e.isAltDown() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P){
                    printAll();
                    e.consume();                           
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    public void printSinglePage(){
        if(tab.getSelectedComponent() instanceof DuctReport)
            PrintUtilities.printComponent(tab.getSelectedComponent(), DuctReport.PRINT_SIZE);
        else if(tab.getSelectedComponent() instanceof Vandy)
            PrintUtilities.printComponent(tab.getSelectedComponent(), Vandy.PRINT_SIZE);
        else
            PrintUtilities.printComponent(tab.getSelectedComponent(), .8);
    }

    public void printAll(){
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.getTabCount(); i ++){
            if(tab.getComponent(i) instanceof DuctReport)
                PrintUtilities.printComponent(tab.getComponent(i), DuctReport.PRINT_SIZE);
            else if(tab.getComponent(i) instanceof Vandy)
                PrintUtilities.printComponent(tab.getComponent(i), Vandy.PRINT_SIZE);
            else
                PrintUtilities.printComponent(tab.getComponent(i), .8);               
        }  
    }
```

here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PrintUtilities
    at Main.printSinglePage(Main.java:282)
    at Main.menPrintAllActionPerformed(Main.java:221)
    at Main.access$600(Main.java:24)
    at Main$8.actionPerformed(Main.java:148)
```

Comment: So, what did you change in the last 10 minutes ?

Comment: i originally just had the code in the processor event without having methods for them, but i switched to methods so i could use elsewhere. i tried putting them back in the event without the methods but it still didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is the result of classloader or classpath issues. Check that a jar hasn't gotten renamed or moved, that your run script is correct, stuff like that. The code's probably fine, it's the environment.

Please consider posting more details of your framework, IDE, and how the apps started if you're still unable to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen weird errors like this when working in NetBeans.  I often do a "Clean and Build" to fix it.  Sometimes is is necessary to shut down NetBeans and clear the NB cache.

Comment: I just created a new project and copied and pasted the classes from the old one and it works just fine now, thanks all who helped =)

Answer (score 0):

It's an environment problem, usually cleaning and rebuilding the project solves the problem.

Comment: I just cleaned and built it but still no luck, so i made a test application to test just that code and it worked just fine. Any ideas of what i should do then? just copy and paste all of the classes to the test application?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error a few times. The main thing that causes it for me is a nullpointerexception during initialization. The second thing is working with static variables when initializing, apparently you can't work with any static array directly (and trying to use methods led to this).

Main point: Check your constructor and make sure there aren't any exceptions there, that's what causes it for me.